# Import-CSV match multiple keyword

Tags: match, keyword-search, import-csv

In a nutshell, I have an excel file that I need :
- Only 2 Columns (ComputerName, Results)
- Only need rows that contain specific items (IE. Start with DriveLetter:\, HKLM, %windir%, etc.)

I'm just not sure on the proper keyword syntax here.  The original file is an xlsx.
Please forgive the crudeness of my script.  I gathered bits and pieces trying to get it to work.

```
    #File Import to Variable
Function Remove-File($fileName) {
 if(Test-Path -path $fileName) { Remove-Item -path $fileName }
}

$excelFile = ".\Computers.xlsx"
if(Test-Path -path $excelFile) {
 $csvFile = ($env:temp + "\" + ((Get-Item -path $excelFile).name).Replace(((Get-Item -path $excelFile).extension),".csv"))

 Remove-File $csvFile

 $excelObject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application   
 $excelObject.Visible = $false 
 $workbookObject = $excelObject.Workbooks.Open($excelFile) 
 $workbookObject.SaveAs($csvFile,6) # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279.aspx
 $workbookObject.Saved = $true
 $workbookObject.Close()
 [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbookObject) | Out-Null
 $excelObject.Quit()
 [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelObject) | Out-Null
 [System.GC]::Collect()
 [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 

 $spreadsheetDataObject = Import-Csv -path $csvFile # Use the $spreadsheetDataObject for your analysis

 Remove-File $csvFile
}

#Filter Out All Columns except ComputerName, Results and subseqently create a CSV file
$PathCSV = ".\Computers.csv"
$spreadsheetDataObject | Select-Object ComputerName,Results | Export-Csv -Path $PathCSV -NoTypeInformation

$Keywords = "*HKLM*","*C:\*","*%windir%*"
$Filter = "($(($Keywords|%{[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"))"


Import-CSV $PathCSV | Where-Object{$_Results -match $Keywords} | Export-Csv -Path ".\Computers2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I needed the _.Results..... and I needed to -match $Filter

```
Import-CSV $PathCSV | Where-Object{$_.Results -match $Filter} | Export-Csv -Path ".\Computers2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```